# Text nodes directly inside spoilers are broken in mobile view

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, spoilers

[This answer on puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89479) looks rather weird in the mobile view:

[[image: Screenshot of broken spoiler;]
Click to enlarge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaPpb.png)

Notice how some of the text that's supposed to be hidden inside the spoiler is actually shown above the "click to show spoiler" notice.  Even worse, when you do click the box, the previously hidden content is revealed *but the text that used to be shown disappears!*

[[image: Screenshot of broken spoiler after clicking;]
Click to enlarge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdyhY.png)

---

It turns out that this bug is easy to reproduce: all you have to do is trick the Markdown parser into placing some text directly inside the spoiler `<blockquote>` with no other tags in between.  One way to do that is to include block-level HTML tags like `<pre></pre>` inside the spoiler and have some text immediately after them, like this:

```
>! This is some hidden spoiler text.
>! <pre>This is preformatted text / code inside the spoiler.</pre>
>! This text should be hidden inside the spoiler, but in the mobile view it's not (unless it's in *italics* or **boldface**).
```

Which renders like this:

> This is some hidden spoiler text.
>
> ```
> This is preformatted text / code inside the spoiler.
> ```
>
> This text should be hidden inside the spoiler, but in the mobile view it's not (unless it's in *italics* or **boldface**).

To see how broken that looks in the mobile view, just scroll down and click the "Mobile" link in the footer.

---

In fact, the cause of this bug is also easy to find.  In [mobile.js](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/mobile.en.js), the spoiler hiding is done using the following piece of JS code:

```js
// replace all .spoiler's with a "click to show" box
var hideSpoilers = function () {
    $('.spoiler').each(
        function (index, i) {
            var item = $(i);

            item.removeClass('spoiler').addClass('spoiler-overlay');
            var children = item.children();  // <-- THE BUG IS HERE!

            children.remove();

            item.append('<div class="spoiler-click-to-show">' + "Click to show spoiler" + '</div>');

            item.one(
                'click',
                function () {
                    item.empty();
                    item.append(children);
                    item.removeClass('spoiler-overlay').addClass('spoiler');
                }
            );
        }
    );
};
```

I've added a comment above pointing out where the bug is: on the marked line, the code uses the jQuery [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method when it *should* be using [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/).

The difference between the two functions is that `.children()` only returns the HTML tags nested inside the parent tag, but skips over any text nodes that are direct descendants of the parent.  So, for example, given the HTML code:

```html
<blockquote class="spoiler">
   <p>This is some hidden spoiler text.</p>

   <pre>This is preformatted text / code inside the spoiler.</pre>

   This text should be hidden inside the spoiler, but in the mobile view
   it's not (unless it's in <em>italics</em> or <strong>boldface</strong>).
</blockquote>
```

calling `.children()` on the `<blockquote>` element will select the `<p>`, `<pre>`, `<em>` and `<strong>` tags and their contents, but not the text that is placed directly inside the blockquote.

Anyway, just changing that single line of code to use the correct jQuery method should be sufficient to fix this bug.